# iPhone dev - How can I find out at runtime what the top cell that's currently being displayed is in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there any way to know which cells are currently being displayed? I'm guessing there might be some type of array property that would store the cells currently on the screen, with the top-most cells having the lowest indexes in the array, or something along those lines. Is there anything like this out there? If not, how could I go about figuring this out?

Comment: Are you populating your table from an array? What is populating the table?

Comment: Yes, it's being populated by an array

Comment: try the answer I just posted, it may be useful even if it's not exactly what you need (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[visibleCells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [indexPathsForVisibleRows](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathsForVisibleRows) is what you are looking for.

- `visibleCells` returns an array of `UITableViewCell` objects.
- `indexPathForVisibleRows` returns an array of `NSIndexPath` objects.

Comment: Yep, there it is, exactly what I needed. Should've just checked the class reference first. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-[UITableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]`, which returns an NSArray of NSIndexPaths for all visible rows. If you need to get access to the actual cell you can use `-[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` on an individual NSIndexPath, or you can use `-[UITableView visibleCells]` to get an array of the actual cells themselves.

Answer (score 0):

In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, try to append `indexPath` to the content you're displaying?

So instead of `cell = something;`, do `cell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %d", something, indexPath];`

Answer (score 0):

```
UITableViewCell *thisCell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[myArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Then, thisCell is an actual cell, so you can call stuff like `thisCell.textLabel.text`, or any other properties of cells.